# Retrieve "number" Luis entity in bot framework and display it right away

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to recognize the entity "number" associated to the Intent command.

Here my entity in Luis [image]

I use the Core Bot example and i let the classes names stay the same. https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot

I added the "number" entity here in flightbooking.cs

```
// Built-in entities
            public DateTimeSpec[] datetime;
            public double[] number;
```

I added this in flightbookingex.cs

```
public string Order_Number
            => Entities.number.ToString();
```

I created a class here : Order_Details.cs

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class Order_Details
    {
        public string Order_Number { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And when i want to retrieve the result in maindialog.cs

```
case FlightBooking.Intent.commande:
                    var commandemessagetext = "Voici le bon de commande";
                    var orderDetails = new Order_Details()
                    {
                        // Get destination and origin from the composite entities arrays.
                        Order_Number = luisResult.Order_Number,
                    };

                    var travelDateMsg = { result.Order_Number };
```

It says `Cannot initialize an implicitly-typed variable with an array initializer` and  `The name 'result' does not exist in the current context`

I did not find another way to do this. I would like to display the result of travelDateMsg in the "case FlightBooking.Intent.commande". In the core bot example, it is displayed in another stepcontext.

i also tried the following piece of code, but it somehow does not work properly.

```
                case FlightBooking.Intent.commande:

                    var commandemessagetext = "Here the order";

                    var order_count= luisResult.Entities;

                    var messageTexto = $"you have ordered {order_count}";
                    var message = MessageFactory.Text(messageTexto, messageTexto, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);
```

the result is `"you have ordered Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.FlightBooking+_Entities"`

Is there a simple way to return the value of an ententy in the same block of code than the one who detect the intent?

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion on this

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second error `The name 'result' does not exist in the current context` is because you have a typo:

```
case FlightBooking.Intent.commande:
                    var commandemessagetext = "Voici le bon de commande";
                    var orderDetails = new Order_Details()
                    {
                        // Get destination and origin from the composite entities arrays.
                        Order_Number = luisResult.Order_Number,
                    };

                    var travelDateMsg = { result.Order_Number };
```

There isn't a `result` there, there's a `luisResult`.

Comment: thanks @JJ_Wailes; second error did go away. The first error is still there